# Any ideas for making sound for a hovering object?

Tags: magical, recommendations

Tasked with creating sounds for various states of an object in a flash game. The "idle", triggered upon mouseover, causes the object (a magic lamp) to merely hover. A simple, half-second, once up / once down, hovering motion. I'm drawing a blank on what to do for that. If it was a scifi object hovering, I'd have a couple ideas, but hovering in general makes me think "silence." I might simply make a design decision and not create a sound, but assuming I do make one, I'd love suggestions for what would be good. A small musical cue, maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try some "whoosh" sounds, like playing a sword fight with an open PVC pipe. then altering the speed and pitch to something more 'natural' and maybe creating a loop from it.

It does not need to be loud in the mix, a little subtlety to it should do the trick... I imagine.

Comment: interesting. that's kind of where my thoughts were going. thanks, man.

Comment: The "whooshes" are a great idea.  Also, if it needs that little "magic" touch, try tweaking some chimes and mixing them in to where they're barely there.

Answer (score 3):

For the 'hovering': maybe try adding just a touch of low end wave beating? Just enough to 'feel' it rather than being obviously machine-like (like a UFO).

Two low freq waveforms [sine, square, miss-matched?] slightly out of sync to create a slow oscillation.

The oscillation beat could than be ramped-up or down, by increasing/decreasing this difference in oscillation freq. [creating faster/slower 'beats'] to help with the illusion of rising/falling - as an addition to the whooshes or chimes effect?

r

Answer (score 0):

Ya I imagine if its a magic lamp keep it as subtle and light as possible. It could have musicality to it but it doesn't have to be a music cue per-say